# MatLab - Execute functions base on their name

Tags: file, matlab

I have a couple of MatLab function, and almost all of them have a test function. There is not really a naming convention right now for test functions, so I end up with functions like `test_functionName`, `tests_functionName`, `FunctionName_Test`, etc.

Howerver, I see two things these functions have in common :

- The name contains "test" (with different casing).
- They have no input or output parameters.

I would like to write a function that would find, under a given folder (or in the PATH), all the functions that respect these two conditions and execute them. This way I could execute all my tests functions in one single call.

Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as follow:

```
fun=dir('*test*.m'); %% look for matlab scripts which name contains 'test'
fun={fun.name};      %% extract their names
fun=fun(cellfun(@(x) (nargin(x)==0),fun)); %% select the ones with no input arguments
fun = regexprep(fun, '.m', ''); % remove '.m' from the filenames
cellfun(@eval,fun); %% execute them
```

Comment: +1 Good answer! But it will give you FooTestBar.m as well. Not sure OP wanted it

Comment: There must be a regular expression that gives `test` only in the end or beginning. Something like "test*|*test". My regexp skill is rusty :)

Comment: It's nice, but then I need to _execute_ these functions.

Comment: And ideally it needs to find functions recursively in folders and subfolders.

Comment: @Johnny5, I added the execution. Concerning, the recursive thing... It would take a few more lines. But I guess you can do it yourself. Just use `dir()`, look at the field `isdir` of the output to select the direcoties, check if it is not '.' or '..',  then enter the directory using `cd`, do your stuff, do the recursion, then exit the directory using `cd..`. I believe in you, I am sure you'll be able to do it.

Comment: I added `fun = regexprep(fun, '.m', '')` before execution part and it works. As for the recursion, maybe I'll be lazy and move all of my tests under the same folder ^^

Answer (score 1):

First, get all files under your folder:

```
    d = dir(myFolder);
```

Remove those whose extension is not `.m` :

```
   indexes = strcmp('.m',{d.ext});
   d(indexes) = [];
```

Then, collect all of their names:

```
   fileNames = {d.Name};
```

Check which one start or end with test:

```
   testPrefix = strncmp('test',fileNames)
   testPostfix = %# Left as an exercise to the reader
   sutiableFileNames = fileNames( testPrefix | testPostfix);
```

Now you can check the amount of parameters using `nargin':

```
   numOfInParams  = cellfun(@nargin,sutiableFileNames);
   numOfOutParams = cellfun(@nargout,sutiableFileNames);
```

And then filter again (I think you already got the idea)